# As the newest questions located on the main page with the new nav, all the low-score posts are hidden

Tags: bug, question-lists, new-nav

Typically, the low-score posts are not hidden from the such views as "newest questions" on the meta sites, because on metas the low-score most of the time means disagreement with the question, and in more rare cases, it's quality. They are only hidden on the main page.

But with the new-nav, the main page also serves as "newest questions" and anything else (just the parameter `?tab=XXX` changes), so without using the advanced search, it's impossible to see the low-score questions.

Proofs, the "newest question" as viewed using incognito and normal browsing:

> **MSO, incognito**
>
> [image]
>
> **MSO, logged in**
>
> [image]

---

> **MSE, incognito**
>
> [image]
>
> **MSE, logged in**
>
> [image]

Is it a bug, or intentional?

**Also**, it causes misunderstandings between ones using the old and the new navs.

Comment: Questions of score -8 are always hidden from the main page on metas, so the issue is more of what to do now that the new nav serves as both views.

Comment: Main sites do the same thing, but with a lower threshold (-4 instead of -8). I reported this internally last week... should've thought to make a meta post, but creating a Trello card was faster. =)

Comment: Hmmm... completely hiding low voted posts (unless you have a direct link), sound like a pretty good feature if you ask me

Comment: I can see missing out on some possibly interesting stuff, but yes this sounds like a good thing to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "new nav" has been deprecated for a year now.

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to happen. Case in point: [What can we do about systemic lies regarding Monica's suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337569/what-can-we-do-about-systemic-lies-regarding-monicas-suspension).

I might disagree vehemently with the asker, but the fact that a few other Random Internet Users (including me) don't like it aren't a reason to hide it.

Free speech includes people who are wrong, and the asker nor any answerer were rude. Therefore, I don't see why any question should be hidden on Meta based on score.

Of course, it's a totally different thing on main sites, where it's an indicator of quality.

Comment: The feature being referred to in the question no longer exists.